# How to confirm the img file copy, conversion is completed, using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

In my node application `fs` and `gm` to copy and conversion img file,
How to check whether the copy and conversion particular stream is complete or not ?

ex:  Img is picture url array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Img.length; i++) {
    // copy img file , how to check this [i] img is copy complete
    fs.createReadStream('/' + Img[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/' + pngImg[i] + '_copy.png');

    gm('/' + Img[i].'_copy.png')
        .stream('jpg', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            fs.createWriteStream('/' + Img[i].jpg);
            stdout.pipe(writeStream);
        });  // conversion img png to jpg , how to check this [i] img is conversion complete


    fs.unlink('/' + Img[i] + '_copy.png'), function (err) {
        console.log('successfully deleted');
    });
}
```

Or whether there is a better way? to complete copy, conversion and delete.

Comment: the stream should emit an event 'end' when it is done. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

Comment: Can you give me an example? thx~

Comment: What is the getReadableStreamSomehow() function, how to using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a copy of the original file only for the conversion, you don't need to do that. Your conversion can be straightforward:

```
var images = [
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png'
];

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var file = images[i];
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/' + file + '.jpg');

    gm(__dirname + '/' + file)
        .stream('jpg')
        .pipe(writeStream)
        .on('finish', (function done(file) {
            console.log('done: ' + file);
        }).bind(null, file));
}
```

Comment: I need the original file. Converting the original file will disappear.

Comment: thank! I try it, but I still want to know how to confirmed the action has been completed.

Comment: What is the function of this bind(null, file)?

Comment: The `.on('finish')` tells you when the conversion is done. I'm using `.bind(null, file)` to capture the file variable, if I don't do that, it will log `done: image3.png` 3 times ([question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), the [answer with bind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19323214/5388620)).

Comment: thank. In bind(null, file) function, what is the "null" parameter? how to using the parameter.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The first parameter is the `this` I'd have inside the `done()` function, I don't use `this` so I set it to null. The rest of the bind parameters are passed to the function (`file` for example), notice `function done(file)`.